# Invalid literal for int() with base10

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, ros

As hard as it is for me to explain my problem, here goes my best:

Im trying to, in a first step, confirm if a certain position of a previously created array is 0 and do replace that 0 with a string. After that I want to confirm if this same position is 0 again and if its not , join the previous string with a new one.

For better understanding I will show a piece of my code:

```
room1=np.array([["chair","table","book","computer","person"],[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

The above is the array(or matrix)

```
if int(room1[1,k])==0:
     room1[1,k]=tipoObjF[1] #tipoObjF[1] being the string I want to replace the 0
else:
     room1[1,k]=room1[1,k]+tipoObjF[1]
```

Here is where I want to do as I mentioned before: Check if a certain position is 0 and if it is, replace it with a String. Otherwise just join both Strings.

When im running it the following error appears:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10: 'chair1'
```

I hope I was able to properly explain my problem.
This error appears in a project im working on using ROS and chair1 is the first thing that replaces the 0 and is what should be joining in the else statement making it Chair1Chair1 the result im expecting.

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help

Edit:
In the end the array should look as follows:

```
room1=np.array([["chair","table","book","computer","person"],["chair1chair",0,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: desired output is useful here, it's currently invisible :-) (you didn't show it in the question)

Comment: Sorry, but I didnt understand you. I have written the desired output in end of the post. Should I include it somewhere else?

Comment: Could it be that `room[1, k]` is not a string? Little rusty on the python but if `int` leads in `+` shouldn't the second be an `int`?

Comment: It should also contain what the code should return...

Comment: @U9-Forward Since its ROS I dont really have a way to display what it should do cuz it should just really change the array. but I'll edit it to try to be more specific. Thank you!

Comment: Or rather, not an `int`. That's the error I get with `int("hello")`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils But it only does the + when its not a int.

Comment: @JoãoVieira `int(room1[1,k])` is causing the issue.

Comment: Oooooh I see what you mean. Is there a way to not "cast" it from string to int and have it check all the same?

Comment: @JoãoVieira You can convert, but it needs to be a valid integer. `int('42')` is fine, but `int('foo')` is not.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I see. Maybe i cant do the way im trying to do. 0 Is really a default value, so maybe changing it for another thats not a integer but a string could solve the problem

Comment: @JoãoVieira In only the code that is given, it works fine. Your error is not reproducible.

Comment: @JoãoVieira Thanks so much for the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to cast `room[1,k]` to an `int` *after* the element has been swapped for a non-integer string, you can't call `int()` on it any longer. For example, `int("chair1chair")` throws the error you see.

Because the values may be `int` or `string`, you can instead start by comparing string values like:

```
if str(room[1,k]) == "0": ...
```

Doing so allows `str(0) == "0"` to return `True` but also `str("hello") == "0"` to return `False`.

Comment: "Because the values may be `int`" No, I think it's only going to be a string. `np.array(['foo', 0])` returns `array(['foo', '0'], dtype='<U3')`.

Comment: @Tomothy32, maybe I read it incorrectly. It seems the array is initialized with a mix-typed matrix. So, if they traverse the integer containing list while it still only contains `int`s, no problem. But if they swap an `int` for a non-integer string, they'll have issues with `int("somestring")`; correct?

Comment: The way it's defined in the question, numpy's going to return `array([['chair', 'table', 'book', 'computer', 'person'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']], dtype='<U8')`, so no mixed types. But yes, your point about swapping for a string and using `int` is correct.

Comment: @Tomothy32, good to know; thanks. So, given the acceptance, why do you think this solves it for them if they've been string all along?

Comment: Basically, as you said, if they use `int` on a non-int string, there's going to be problems. It seems like OP's condition was trying to check if `room[1,k]` was `'0'` in some form. `str()` never fails on anything, so your solution works. What I was trying to say was that `room[1,k]` will always be a string, so the `str` conversion is superfluous, but it by no means breaks the program.